# Testing a typeclass with MonadIO: "No instance nor default method" error

Tags: haskell, io-monad, hspec

I have a typeclass that performs some IO. I've generalised it a little using `MonadIO`:

```
class MonadIO m => MonadDB m where
    getSomething :: String -> m Something
    getSomething s = -- do some IO stuff with liftIO
```

In a test I wish to replace the implementation so I can test a function that uses `getSomething`, so I do this:

```
newtype WorkingDBM a = WorkingDBM (Identity a)
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

instance MonadDB WorkingDBM where
    getSomething s = return $ Something "blah"
```

Without an instance declaration the code warns:

```
• No explicit implementation for ‘liftIO’
• In the instance declaration for ‘MonadIO WorkingDBM’
```

So I add:

```
instance MonadIO WorkingDBM
```

which of course compiles.

Running the tests in Hspec causes this runtime error:

```
uncaught exception: NoMethodError (test/BlahSpec.hs:45:10-33: No instance nor default method for class operation liftIO
```

I have tried using `liftIO` from `Control.Monad.IO.Class`:

```
-- C is the qualified import for Control.Monad.IO.Class
liftIO = C.liftIO
```

but this results in a `NonTermination` runtime exception:

```
uncaught exception: NonTermination (<<loop>>)
```

Any ideas how I can resolve this please?

Comment: Don't do `IO` in your test, or support real `IO` in `WorkingDBM`.

Comment: Turns out it was `liftIO` in the function that I was testing, so I can't _not_ do the IO. What do you mean support real? I thought `MonadIO` would suffice for that.

Comment: I have written an answer with some further details on what I mean. But I challenge your claim that you must do `IO` inside the `MonadDB` instance in your test.

Comment: I didn't say I need to do IO inside `MonadDB`; I need to use `liftIO` inside the function that I'm testing (which uses the `MonadDB` instance).

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you are trying to draw in your last comment. Somehow I feel there is a fundamental misunderstanding between the three of us (you, me, and the compiler), but I haven't seen enough details about your beliefs to have figured out what it is yet.

Comment: I assure you the misunderstanding is all mine. I've realised that even though I'm using this technique for testing IO-driven functions, the function under test stiil doesn't ultimately use my test instance as described in this question, so I'm still stuck. For background: my test target is a Pipe function that uses the MonadDB shown here (a real version of it of course). It's _that function's_ usage I want to "mock", and I thought this would achieve it, but alas I've realised my mistake. I hope that makes sense? PS you've solved the question of course, as `liftIO` was what I was asking about.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. It sounds like it might be worth opening a fresh question with further details.

Comment: Yep, fair point. I've raised http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41694407/unit-testing-ip-actions-with-hspec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to support real `IO` in `WorkingDBM`. For example:

```
newtype WorkingDBM a = WorkingDBM (IO a) -- N.B. IO not Identity
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

instance MonadIO WorkingDBM where
    liftIO = WorkingDBM
```

The derived instance for `MonadIO` will also work fine; but the empty instance will not, as it is equivalent to

```
instance MonadIO WorkingDBM where
    liftIO = undefined
```

which will obviously blow up the first time you try to actually do `IO`.

Comment: Thanks. How would I force usage of `WorkingDBM`? I currently use `unWorkingDBM (WorkingDBM (Identity x)) = x` in my test which obviously triggers the compiler to use my "teset instance" of `MonadDB`. Not having an equivalent when `IO a`  is used (because of no data constructor for `IO` means I can't push the compiler to use the test instance (derived or otherwise...)

Comment: @atc You can still write `runWorkingDBM (WorkingDBM x) = x`, you just have to give it type `runWorkingDBM :: WorkingDBM a -> IO a` rather than `runWorkingDBM :: WorkingDBM a -> a`.