# Testing user input with Hspec

Tags: haskell, testing, hspec

I have a program that takes a user input from `getLine` then validates that it is all numbers. If it passes it runs a function of `String -> String` and prints the result to screen. If not it repeats the `getLine`.

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.Loops (untilJust)
import Data.Char           (isDigit)

main = do
  let validateInput s = if all isDigit s then Just s else Nothing
  putStrLn =<< myFunc <$> untilJust (validateInput <$> (putStr "Number : " >> getLine))

myFunc = id -- to do
```

How do I test the this main function with something like `Hspec` to check that it does the right thing with a number input vs other inputs (letters, empty etc)

ie

```
test1 rejects a non-numeric input of "abc"
test2 returns 123 as 123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to test the logic rather than the user interaction, I'd suggest that you simply factor out the input validation.

Comment: well, I think I want a bit more than just the logic. I essentially want to test it from the end point ie I want to test my entire programs functionality against a set of possible inputs. I would indeed test `myFunc` and test `validateInput` ... however I want to test everything as a whole... if that is possible at all.

Comment: I answered based on the output example you provided. I'm not sure if you can test IO easily with HSpec, but if you want to test the 'plumbing', I suppose you could use a different monad that emulates IO, feeding data and recording output. Maybe something like the State monad.

Comment: @matthias [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41699338/2670439) seems to suggest a similar approach.

Comment: @matthias Does that answer your question in full?

Comment: sorry, have not been at a computer all day. I think your question answers enough and points me in the right direction. Thanks